# The query is using a variable but i dont know why, can you help me?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What does this code do? [Image to show code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFiO3.jpg)

```
$q57 = mysqli_query($Link, 'select count(*) Registos from t57 where c18="1"') ;
$t57 = mysqli_fetch_array($q57) ;
if($t57['Registos'] == 0) {
```

what i don't understand is that variable "Registos" in front of the count. Is it doing what there?

Comment: Whoever came up with the variable and column and table names needs to read about how to make code maintainable!

Comment: That is simply an _alias_, to help you access the result of `count(*)` (otherwise _that_ would be the column name in the result set), the `as` keyword between the two is optional. https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/

Answer (score -1):

That is simply an *alias*, to help you access the result of `count(*)`.

Otherwise *that* would become the column name in the result set - remove `Registos` from the query, and then do a `var_dump($t57);`, you’ll see what I mean.

The `as` keyword between the two is optional; `select count(*) as Registos` would be the “long” way of writing this.

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/